# XSLT Help - Store field mapping into a variable and group the input pay load based on that mapping

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have an XML file that needs to be converted to pipe delimited text file. In addition, the xml contains legacy pay codes which need to be translated to future state codes in the output file. The mapping between those codes in either 1:1 or M:1.For example, if 4 lines of input data with different codes correspond to one code in future state, the output should produce one row with amounts summed up. Here is an example,

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/ERP-PAY-CR_PAYROLL_BALANCES_-_CX">
<wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Legal_Entity_Name wd:Descriptor="Wayne Enterprises">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">66b06c2b4ec001df7d2d7875ea020e52</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
</wd:Legal_Entity_Name>
<wd:Person_Number>2100003</wd:Person_Number>
<wd:Calendar_Quarter wd:Descriptor="2019-Q1">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">da9970b23fce10001102e89a634e0024</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Calendar_Quarter">2019-Q1</wd:ID>
</wd:Calendar_Quarter>
<wd:Pay_Component_Code>102</wd:Pay_Component_Code>
<wd:Result_Line_Amount>14326.91</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Legal_Entity_Name wd:Descriptor="Wayne Enterprises">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">66b06c2b4ec001df7d2d7875ea020e52</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
</wd:Legal_Entity_Name>
<wd:Person_Number>2100003</wd:Person_Number>
<wd:Calendar_Quarter wd:Descriptor="2019-Q1">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">da9970b23fce10001102e89a634e0024</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Calendar_Quarter">2019-Q1</wd:ID>
</wd:Calendar_Quarter>
<wd:Pay_Component_Code>123</wd:Pay_Component_Code>
<wd:Result_Line_Amount>1175.56</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Legal_Entity_Name wd:Descriptor="Wayne Enterprises">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">66b06c2b4ec001df7d2d7875ea020e52</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
</wd:Legal_Entity_Name>
<wd:Person_Number>2100003</wd:Person_Number>
<wd:Calendar_Quarter wd:Descriptor="2019-Q1">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">da9970b23fce10001102e89a634e0024</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Calendar_Quarter">2019-Q1</wd:ID>
</wd:Calendar_Quarter>
<wd:Pay_Component_Code>126</wd:Pay_Component_Code>
<wd:Result_Line_Amount>2350.74</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Legal_Entity_Name wd:Descriptor="Wayne Enterprises">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">66b06c2b4ec001df7d2d7875ea020e52</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
</wd:Legal_Entity_Name>
<wd:Person_Number>2100003</wd:Person_Number>
<wd:Calendar_Quarter wd:Descriptor="2019-Q1">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">da9970b23fce10001102e89a634e0024</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Calendar_Quarter">2019-Q1</wd:ID>
</wd:Calendar_Quarter>
<wd:Pay_Component_Code>217</wd:Pay_Component_Code>
<wd:Result_Line_Amount>0.85</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Legal_Entity_Name wd:Descriptor="Wayne Enterprises">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">66b06c2b4ec001df7d2d7875ea020e52</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
</wd:Legal_Entity_Name>
<wd:Person_Number>2100003</wd:Person_Number>
<wd:Calendar_Quarter wd:Descriptor="2019-Q1">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">da9970b23fce10001102e89a634e0024</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Calendar_Quarter">2019-Q1</wd:ID>
</wd:Calendar_Quarter>
<wd:Pay_Component_Code>225</wd:Pay_Component_Code>
<wd:Result_Line_Amount>1.03</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Legal_Entity_Name wd:Descriptor="Wayne Enterprises">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">66b06c2b4ec001df7d2d7875ea020e52</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
</wd:Legal_Entity_Name>
<wd:Person_Number>2100003</wd:Person_Number>
<wd:Calendar_Quarter wd:Descriptor="2019-Q1">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">da9970b23fce10001102e89a634e0024</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Calendar_Quarter">2019-Q1</wd:ID>
</wd:Calendar_Quarter>
<wd:Pay_Component_Code>353</wd:Pay_Component_Code>
<wd:Result_Line_Amount>21.84</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Legal_Entity_Name wd:Descriptor="Wayne Enterprises">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">66b06c2b4ec001df7d2d7875ea020e52</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">G01A</wd:ID>
</wd:Legal_Entity_Name>
<wd:Person_Number>2100003</wd:Person_Number>
<wd:Calendar_Quarter wd:Descriptor="2019-Q1">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">da9970b23fce10001102e89a634e0024</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Calendar_Quarter">2019-Q1</wd:ID>
</wd:Calendar_Quarter>
<wd:Pay_Component_Code>420</wd:Pay_Component_Code>
<wd:Result_Line_Amount>1632.61</wd:Result_Line_Amount>
</wd:Report_Entry>

</wd:Report_Data>
```

Mapping Reference:

```
Legacy Codes   Future State Values
102            Regular
123            Regular
126            Regular
217            Diff Shift Prod
225            Diff Shift Prod
353            PTO Donation
420            PTO Donation
```

Expected output:

```
Legal Entity Name|Person Number|Calendar Quarter|Pay Component Code|Result Line Amount
Wayne Enterprises|2100003|2019-Q1|Regular|17853.21
Wayne Enterprises|2100003|2019-Q1|Diff Shift Prod|1.88
Wayne Enterprises|2100003|2019-Q1|PTO Donation|1654.45
```

Essentially the way I'd envision is to create a mapping variable and I'm okay hard coding all the mapping in my code and group the amounts based on the new code. Attaching my xsl code if it is of any help. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/ERP-PAY-CR_PAYROLL_BALANCES_-_CX"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pipe" select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="EffectiveStartDate" select="'1951-01-01'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="EffectiveEndDate" select="'4712-12-31'"/>

    <xsl:param name="quote">"</xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!--  File Header Record  -->
        <!-- ERP1 -->
        <xsl:call-template name="Write-Header-Record0"/>
        <!--  File Detail Layout  -->
        <xsl:for-each
            select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">

                <xsl:call-template name="Write-Detail-Record"/>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- File Header Record 0-->
    <xsl:template name="Write-Header-Record0">

        <xsl:text>Legal Entity Name|Person Number|Calendar Quarter|Pay Component Code|Result Line Amount</xsl:text>

        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Write-Detail-Record">

        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Legal_Entity_Name/@wd:Descriptor"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Person_Number"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Calendar_Quarter/@wd:Descriptor"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Pay_Component_Code"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Result_Line_Amount"/>



        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>


    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In your example, all the entries have the same Legal Entity Name, Person Number and Calendar Quarter. Will that always be the case? If not, what should each row of the output represent?

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response. It worked great for my sample data. Great question! The amount need to be grouped based on pay codes for a unique combination of Person number > Legal Employer > Calendar quarter. Do I need to update the group-by value to include these three attributes? Also, can you help me understand the syntax: group-by="key('paycode', wd:Pay_Component_Code, $payCodes) as I may have to enhance it further.

Comment: I believe you need to group by the combination of those 3 properties first, then do the grouping shown in my answer within each outer group. -- Not sure which part of the syntax needs clarifying. The key selects a `payCode` by `legacyCode` - so calling the key with **any** of its legacy codes selects the correct `payCode`. For more, see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot. I ran into another issue. There are some legacy codes in input xml that are not mapped in XSLT. In those cases, I would like the programto print one row per legacy code with legacy pay component name and corresponding amount. Right now, the program group all the unidentified legacy codes and prints one row with summed ammount. Is it possible to do so? Pl let me know if this needs to be another post.

Comment: Try branching the processing of each group based upon the existence of `current-grouping-key()`.

Comment: Thank you! As you said, I applied a condition to print only if match in key exists. I ran the program for one company and it worked fine. When I run it for another company, I get the following error: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of concat() (<payCode/>, <payCode/>)Line:1786Column:11
I understand this happens when the node in context has multiple child elements. Can you please explain where the issue might be? Oxygen editor highlights the whole xml indicating the warning.The input xml is too long to analyse the issue. Posting my xslt in my next comment.

Comment: I don't know. I suggest you post a new question, with a [mcve] showing the current problem.

Comment: No worries. Posted a new question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490430/xslt-help-create-a-varibale-in-xslt-to-store-cross-reference-mapping-and-group
Any guidance is greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/ERP-PAY-CR_PAYROLL_BALANCES_-_CX">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="payCodes">
    <payCode name="Regular">
        <legacyCode>102</legacyCode>
        <legacyCode>123</legacyCode>
        <legacyCode>126</legacyCode>
    </payCode>
    <payCode name="Diff Shift Prod">
        <legacyCode>217</legacyCode>
        <legacyCode>225</legacyCode>
    </payCode>
    <payCode name="PTO Donation">
        <legacyCode>353</legacyCode>
        <legacyCode>420</legacyCode>
    </payCode>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="paycode" match="payCode" use="legacyCode" />

<xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">
    <xsl:variable name="common">
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Report_Entry[1]/wd:Legal_Entity_Name/@wd:Descriptor"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Report_Entry[1]/wd:Person_Number"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Report_Entry[1]/wd:Calendar_Quarter/@wd:Descriptor"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <xsl:text>Legal Entity Name|Person Number|Calendar Quarter|Pay Component Code|Result Line Amount&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <!-- DATA -->
    <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry" group-by="key('paycode', wd:Pay_Component_Code, $payCodes)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$common"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('paycode', wd:Pay_Component_Code, $payCodes)/@name"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/wd:Result_Line_Amount)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26mw

Comment: Simplification: `<xsl:value-of select="wd:Report_Entry[1]/(wd:Legal_Entity_Name/@wd:Descriptor, wd:Person_Number, wd:Calendar_Quarter/@wd:Descriptor)" separator="|"/>`